# Triggering a collapsable panel without an id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, phpbb3

I'm implementing an spoiler box bbcode in phpbb which uses an bootstrap-based style.

But i'm having problems since phpbb dont give any unique identifier for each bbcode processed, so i cant use an id for the collapsible div due to inevitable duplication of the code every time a member uses the bbcode in a text.

The base html is like this:

```
<div class="panel-group">
<div class="panel panel-warning">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">SPOILER!</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">{TEXT}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So how i can make the panel body collapsable without an id?

Thanks.

Comment: The `id` doesn't need to be descriptive, just unique... can you get phpbb to generate a random string of characters and set that as an ID?

Comment: Sadly nope. I dont find anything about a automatic generation of any string or character for each bbcode, and even an `{IDENTIFIER}` i thought can be something like this showed to be just another type of data user need to enter.

Comment: Use something else from the dataset then, such as the post name or something. Otherwise just number them off as you loop, so like id="collapse-{post-number}"

Comment: Sadly, according [with the bbcode docs](https://www.phpbb.com/support/docs/en/3.1/kb/article/adding-custom-bbcodes-in-phpbb3/) i cant extract any information about the thread or something. So i planned to make an alternative selection "marking" the collapse1 div with a custom class and select it using [tree transversing](https://api.jquery.com/parent/). But it didnt work due to my inexperience with javascript.

Comment: This sounds goofy and complicated. Do you have access to the template? The template must show some bbcode data (such as `{TEXT}`). How is that text being displayed? Repeat that process for each id like: `id="{IDENTIFIER}"`... plz explain how this wouldn't work, bc according to the docs this is what should be expected...

Comment: The bbcodes are added separately, not to do with the style.
I just wanted to add a code compatible with bootstrap, since [the snippets available in phpbb site](https://www.phpbb.com/customise/db/bbcode/new_spoiler/) are awful and truly goofy.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the PT stackoverflowers were fast.

Here the translated [answer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111176/como-usar-um-collapsible-sem-um-id-para-o-elemento-alvo/111189?noredirect=1#comment230949_111189):

```
<div class="panel panel-warning">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" onclick="$(this).parents().next('div.panel-collapse.collapse').collapse('toggle');">SPOILER!</a>
        </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">{SPOILER}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Isnt the best form, but if you cant get any ID, its an alternative.

Here the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/52VtD/14062/)